# actionlib sendgoal arguments

Tags: ros, actionlib, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I'm following the ROS-I tutorial (http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/demo/part4.3), and I get stuck when I have to send a goal to the server using the sendGoal method. Reading the sendGoal reference (http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#ae6a2e6904495e7c20c59e96af0d86801) I should provide the goal and three  callback functions.

Do I have to manually define those callback functions?

However in line 32, I tried to insert  those callback funcs as indicated in the reference but Eclipse says "Method 'sendGoal' could not be resolved".
What should I do?

Thank you!

```
  #include <collision_avoidance_pick_and_place/pick_and_place.h>

/*    SET GRIPPER
  Goal:
      - Turn the vacuum gripper on or off.
  Hints:
      - Use the grasp action client to send an grasp request to the grasp server.
      - Confirm that the gripper was successfully opened or closed and exit on error
*/
void collision_avoidance_pick_and_place::PickAndPlace::set_gripper(bool do_grasp)
{
//  ROS_ERROR_STREAM("set_gripper is not implemented yet.  Aborting."); exit(1);

  // task variables
  object_manipulation_msgs::GraspHandPostureExecutionGoal grasp_goal;
  bool success;

  // set the corresponding gripper action in the "grasp_goal" object.
  if (do_grasp)
    grasp_goal.goal = object_manipulation_msgs::GraspHandPostureExecutionGoal::GRASP;
  else
    grasp_goal.goal = object_manipulation_msgs::GraspHandPostureExecutionGoal::RELEASE;

  /* Fill Code:
   * Goal:
   * - Send the grasp goal to the server.
   * Hints:
   * - Use the "sendGoal" method of the grasp client "grasp_action_client_ptr"
   * to make a call to the server.
   */
  /* ========  ENTER CODE HERE ======== */
  grasp_action_client_ptr.sendGoal(grasp_goal.goal, SimpleDoneCallback, SimpleActiveCallback, SimpleFeedbackCallback) ;


  /* Fill Code:
   * Goal:
   * - Confirm that client service call succeeded.
   * Hints:
   * - Use the "waitForResult" method of the client to wait for completion.
   * - Give "waitForResult" a timeout value of 4 seconds
   * - Timeouts in ros can be created using "ros::Duration(4.0f)".
   * - Save returned boolean from waitForResult() in the "success" variable.
   */
  /* ========  ENTER CODE HERE ======== */

  if(success)
  {
    if (do_grasp)
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("Gripper closed");
    else
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("Gripper opened");
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Gripper failure");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241221/actionlib-sendgoal-arguments/) by [nico_lauda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27695/nico_lauda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-07**:
You have a thing named `grasp_action_client_ptr`, which is probably a pointer, but you're trying to use the dot operator on it. Perhaps you want the deference `->` instead?

**Comment by [nico_lauda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27695/nico_lauda/) on 2016-08-07**:
Thank you for your comment!.
I changed the operator like you said, and now `sendGoal` is recognized, but I get "Invalid arguments" error. It seems that it doesn't recognize the callback functions.
I don't care of the callback fcns, but if I don't put them in the sendGoal I get the error as well.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-07**:
The API docs you link to show defaults for the callbacks, so I don't think you need to provide those arguments. It looks like you're following a tutorial that is mostly pre-filled code, so I'd recommend that you read the examples again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I write this answer in order to help someone else in the future that will find similar difficulties.

I have found [here](https://github.com/Liangconghui/NTU_Amazon_Picking_Challenge/blob/master/demo_manipulation/src/collision_avoidance_pick_and_place/src/tasks/set_gripper.cpp) the same code already solved.
On line 38 just write `grasp_action_client_ptr.sendGoal(grasp_goal);` and It works.

---

Originally posted by [nico_lauda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27695/nico_lauda/) with karma: 16 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0